# pass a input textbox value to another page using href link using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an input tag textbox which has a value and I want that value to be passed from one page to another using a href tag. Is this possible?

Here's my HTML code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Place given Access Key" id="accesskeynum" name="accesskeynum" value="accesskeynum">
```

and here's my code to pass it to another page using php

but when I echo the value in page 2 it returns blank even though I put 1234 in the text field

```
<a href="immobilization_actions.php?action=immobilizerx&id=<?php echo $_POST['accesskeynum'] ?>" style="margin-right:50px;"><img src='style/Immobilize.png' height="75" width="75" onmouseover="this.src='style/Immobilize.png';" onmouseout="this.src='style/Immobilize.png';" /></a>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: You need to submit form to get value in another page.

Comment: … or use JavaScript to read the value, and put it into the URL that the link refers to via its `href` attribute, f.e. as a query string parameter.

Comment: Javascript (or jQuery) is your friend here. Have you tried anything so far in terms of the JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest js solution:

```
<a href="/immobilization_actions.php?action=immobilizerx" onclick="window.location=this.href+'?id='+document.getElementById('accesskeynum').value;return false;">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks a bit messy with inline event handlers which is not good. It's highly recommended to separate behavior from markup (presentation). So, let's try:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Place given Access Key" id="accesskeynum" name="accesskeynum" value="accesskeynum">    

<a href="immobilization_actions.php?action=immobilizerx" style="margin-right:50px;"><img src='style/Immobilize.png' height="75" width="75" /></a>
```

And

```
var ele = document.querySelector("a");
var input =  document.querySelector("#accesskeynum");
ele.href += "&id="+ input.value;

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    ele.href = ele.href.replace(/&id=[^"']*/, "");
    ele.href += "&id="+ this.value;
});

ele.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    this.src='style/Immobilize.png';
});
ele.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    this.src='style/Immobilize.png';
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/sf8cxqy2/3/)